# toyota altezza cutting and maintenance

Tags: toyota, troubleshooting

My toyota altezza is cutting off randomly while driving. I have not been able to purposely reproduce the problem, which makes diagnosis difficult. I am looking for any advice in diagnostics, or parts to test first.

The car will run normally 99% of the time. Without warning, the electrical cuts out and the engine stalls. This has happened at low speed and highway speed, while turning or while going straight down the road. There are no engine error codes, no dash warning lights, and no other indication of what occurred.

After each incident, the car can usually be restarted immediately. Twice, I got a single "click" and no start -- turning the key off and trying again started the car in both of those occasions.

It has been suggested that I check the wiring harness, which I have done by aggressively wiggling and pulling on various engine connections and wires while the car is running -- no results. It has also been suggested that the crankshaft position sensor is faulty or the harness is damaged. Visually, there are no problems with the harness.

Comment: I'm thinking this may have to do with your ignition switch, but it's only a gut check. I don't know if the Altezza (Lexus IS in the States) has had ignition problems in the past. It just seems one area which may be a place for you to look.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?